# How to read data from firebase without specifying the child?

Tags: java, firebase

good day, here is my firebase real-time structure

```
  -User
      |
      |
      -3fh3s2q431yhn6v45
                        |
                        |
                        -phone: "+2348168xxxxx"
                        -name: "Amazinguser"
                        -status: "active"
                        -bio: "*no bio*"
      -64cdw2koysqwvydv45
                        |
                        |
                        -phone: "+2340768xxxxx"
                        -name: "Amazinguser23"
                        -status: "active"
                        -bio: "*no bio*"
      -g6a11qag9gj5urwzak
                        |
                        |
                        -phone: "+2344358xxxxx"
                        -name: "Amazinguser3"
                        -status: "active"
                        -bio: "*no bio*"
```

Here is my java code

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference rf = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

rf.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);

    //Futher implementation on user
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    //Imlementation of errors
  }
});
```

The above code is the sample  of my class which i used in reading the logged user data with its `firebaseUser.getUid()`

Question. How can i read all the User data all together without having to provide or use `firebaseUser.getUid()` in the child method ?
Thanks.

Comment: just remove that .child(firebaseUser.getUid()) and run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `getReference("Users")` you will get all list which is inside the **User** and with Datasnapshot loop you can list down each user. Here is the code:

```
DatabaseReference rf = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
rf.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
  User user = userSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
  //Futher implementation on user
}
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    //Imlementation of errors
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read all users, you can listen to the `/Users` path:

```
DatabaseReference rf = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
```

Since you now get multiple nodes back, your listener will need to loop over those child nodes on its `onDataChange`:

```
rf.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      User user = userSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);

      //Futher implementation on user
    }
  }
  ...
```